# Neural Nets: Backpropogation from Conjugate Gradient Descent

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation

In neural nets, the back-propagation algorithm is 'based on' gradient descent, optimizing over a cost function $C(w,b)$ of the weights and biases of the network.

Conjugate gradient descent has way faster convergence than standard gradient descent (and stochastic gradient descent). Is there a similar back-propagation algorithm based off of conjugate gradient descent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

see the article [Optimization in an error backpropagation neural network environment with a performance test on a spectral pattern classification problem](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=7055976448135115973&hl=de&as_sdt=0,5)